# Donating unwanted foreign coins in Sydney

Tags: money, australia, sydney

More general question: [How do I get money back for my foreign coins?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/how-do-i-get-money-back-for-my-foreign-coins)

I've got some unwanted foreign coins, some of them reasonably obscure (Danish currency) and I want to donate them to charity. I know there's options for donating coins at Sydney Airport, but going there is fairly expensive in either money or time or both. Are there more convenient options in the Sydney CBD, or the North Shore?

Comment: I know of many charities in the United Kingdom that accept ALL foreign coins - you might want to contact Against Breast Cancer in Abingdon England and they have a web site and you can email them and then send them the coins. I have done it many times

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[UNICEF Australia](http://www.unicef.org.au/faqs) will accept them at any Commonwealth Bank or Bankwest branch, and at the Sydney CBD UNICEF office.

> **Does UNICEF accept foreign coins? If so, where can I bring my coins?**
>
> UNICEF Australia accepts local and foreign currency with the support of three of our valuable corporate partners; Qantas, Commonwealth Bank and Bankwest.

Find a Commonwealth Bank branch: https://www.commbank.com.au/personal/locate-us.html

Find a Bankwest branch: http://www.bankwest.com.au/find-us

The UNICEF office: [Level 4, 280 Pitt St, Sydney](https://www.google.com/maps/place/UNICEF/@-33.8741393,151.2081534,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x44bb98ca9137e22d?sa=X&ved=0CF0Q_BIwCmoVChMIk83Al8qnyAIVQ2KmCh212QLL)