# Where can I exchange Canadian loonies and toonies for USD in the US?

Tags: usa, canada, exchange

I recently returned to the USA from an extended trip in Canada with around CAD$25 in loonies and toonies (CAD$1 and CAD$2 coins).  As I won't be returning to Canada for a while, and don't live near Canada, I was hoping to exchange the coins, even at a worse rate (since they're worth nothing to me at the moment).

However, I went to a local Travelex and was told that they did not exchange Canadian coins and indeed, that **no** currency bureaus would take the coins.

Is there anywhere I could go to exchange these coins?

Comment: Go hang out near the Air Canada desk at LAX and offer to sell them to outbound travelers for $10-$15?

Comment: Unless we're talking about thousands of dollars worth of coins, you probably won't be able to exchange them for anything, unless you encounter other people who happen to be traveling to Canada and who'd be willing to make a private trade for them. See *[How do I get money back for my foreign coins?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/how-do-i-get-money-back-for-my-foreign-coins)*

Comment: Congratulations on starting your souvenir foreign coin collection!

Comment: While the 'no exchange office will trade coins' is true in many countries, it is not a given world wide. There are a few chains in several countries which became well known because they do handle coins. Very nice if you go out and want small change as well.